# Lua - fast changing images

Tags: image, background, lua

I'm not a programmer, even amateur, I just wanted a program that would change PSP screen (whole) color as fast as possible infinitely. I made something:

```
rdupa = Image.load("red.png")
gdupa = Image.load("green.png")
bdupa = Image.load("blue.png")
screen:clear()
while true do
screen:blit(0, 0, rdupa, false)
screen:clear()
screen:blit(0, 0, gdupa, false)
screen:clear()
screen:blit(0, 0, bdupa, false)
screen:clear()
end
```

Using Google, but that doesn't work. What did I do wrong (I have *.png images in the same folder as script)? Ready script would be seen veeeeeeery nicely.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what you are using that allows you to run Lua code on the PSP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your environment but I'd guess it's most likely unable to update its main window or whatever as it's essentially stuck executing the Lua code snipped (unless that's executed in a separate thread).

Answer (score 0):

Lua is a small and concise programming language and provides only few core functions (see [this list](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/#index)).

Lua does not provide any functions to work with screen and images by default, so without knowing what library/framework are you using, there is little we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I'm operating under the assumption that you're using [Lua Player](http://www.luaplayer.org/) (consider adding a luaplayer tag?). From what I can see in the [documentation](http://www.luaplayer.org/?page_id=83), you should be using

```
screen.flip()
```

instead of

```
screen:clear()
```

whenever you want to update the screen. Unfortunately, I do not have CFW on my PSP, so I cannot test this myself.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I wouldn't even consider using images.

something like this would do :)

(This is using PGELua but can easily be adapted for LuaPlayer)

```
while pge.running() do
    color = pge.gfx.createcolor(pge.math.rand(255),pge.math.rand(255),pge.math.rand(255))
    pge.gfx.startdrawing()
    pge.gfx.drawrect(0,0,480,272,color)
    pge.gfx.enddrawing()
    pge.gfx.swapbuffers()
end
```

if you want defined colours, maybe something like.

```
red = pge.gfx.createcolor(255,0,0)
gre = pge.gfx.createcolor(0,255,0)
blu = pge.gfx.createcolor(0,0,255)
loop = 1
while pge.running() do
    pge.gfx.startdrawing()
    if loop==1 then
         pge.gfx.drawrect(0,0,480,272,red)
    elseif loop==2 then
         pge.gfx.drawrect(0,0,480,272,gre)
    elseif loop==3 then
         pge.gfx.drawrect(0,0,480,272,blu)
    end
    loop=loop+1
    if loop>4 then
        loop=1
    end
    pge.gfx.enddrawing()
    pge.gfx.swapbuffers()
end
```